# How do i changed Turbo C7 's blue screen to something more pleasing?

Tags: turbo-c

The tc7 screen irritates my eye. I need something peaceful and lite. Is there a way to change or is there any better compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Turbo C/C++ read this  [Why not to use Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-not-to-use-turbo-c)

And i suggest you to use codelite or codeblocks or dev-c++ . You can change background colour , appearance , fonts etc in these types of ide.